# Is it possible to maintain a 'compatible' version of an iOS App

Tags: ios, ipad, version

Over the last few years I have developed a number of iPad apps for which I've maintained backward compatibility to iOS 5. I've decided that I would like to update these apps and was considering dropping support for iOS 5 & 6 so that I can take advantage of new framework features and possibly start using Swift. I understand that Apple will maintain previous versions of my Apps which my customers can still download (for users of the iPad 1 for example). What is not clear to me is how this works. Specifically :-

1. Can a new customer on iOS 5 buy a previous 'compatible' version of my app or is it only for people who have already purchased it?
2. Is there any way to provide updates to these compatible versions of my app if a support issue is raised

The second point is important as if I get a support request for an old version and there is no way to update the app my customer is essentially left no choice but to buy a new device.

Comment: No to both. 1. Only existing users can install a previous purchase. 2. Can only keep the current version up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@rmaddy is right except one thing. There is a trick user can do to implement #1 if he has also newer device. He can purchase latest version on new device and then just download app from already purchased list. In this case Apple would offer user to install latest compatible version ;)

Comment: Thanks Vitaly (and rmaddy) - I think I'll bite the bullet and move to target iOS7+. I haven't had a support issue on the current version in over a year so I think it is reasonable to move on. It looks like ~95% of devices are iOS7 or above anyway.